# ssh from linux into mac - permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm running a Oracle Linux VM on a Windows 7 host and I'm trying to ssh into my MacBook.

I've already created the private/pub keys in my Mac. I have copied the `id_rsa.pub` contents into the `authorized_keys` file in `.ssh` folder.
I have changed the `authorized_keys` permissions to `600` for the current user.
Permissions for `~` and `~/.ssh` have been changed to `700`.

I have also copied the `id_rsa.pub` contents from the Oracle Linux VM to the authorized_keys file using

```
ssh-copy-id
```

In my Mac I also have an Oracle Linux VM into which I can ssh perfectly fine from the Oracle Linux VM in the Windows machine.

However, I cannot ssh into my Mac using just: `ssh macdomain`

I have to use: `ssh username@macdomain`  to ssh successfully. Without the username it will ask me for a password and eventually result in:

```
Permission denied (publickey, keyboard-interactive)
```

This is my sshd_config file:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.81 2009/10/08 14:03:41 markus Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes no
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
AllowUsers username
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords both PasswordAuthentication and
# ChallengeResponseAuthentication must be set to "no".
#PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# Also, PAM will deny null passwords by default.  If you need to allow
# null passwords, add the " nullok" option to the end of the
# securityserver.so line in /etc/pam.d/sshd.
#UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# pass locale information
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org)
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

I've googled and had a look at almost every relevant topic but to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your username in the VM is different than your username on the Mac. By default, `ssh` assumes the usernames are the same if you don't specify it explicitly. It's trying to log in to a user that doesn't exist (or that you haven't set up), which is why it always fails.

To avoid that, you can either specify the username each time, or set up your [`.ssh/config` file](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?&manpath=OpenBSD-current&sec=5&query=ssh_config) in the VM like this:

```
Host mac
    Hostname macdomain
    User yourmacusername
```

That will override the default username for that host only. You would also be able to just `ssh mac` if you prefer, rather than using the hostname.